# How to write MatLab Code for bimodal Probability Density Functions?

Tags: matlab, math, statistics

I want to write a bimodal Probability Density Function (PDF with multiple peaks, Galtung S) without using the pdf function from statistics toolbox. Here is my code:

```
x = 0:0.01:5;
d = [0.5;2.5];  
a = [12;14];    % scale parameter
y =  2*a(1).*(x-d(1)).*exp(-a(1).*(x-d(1)).^2) +  ...
     2*a(2).*(x-d(2)).*exp(-a(2).*(x-d(2)).^2);
plot(x,y)
```

Here's the curve.
[plot(x,y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GYTJ.png)

I would like to change the mathematical formula to to get rid of the dips in the curve that appear at approx. `0<x<.5` and `2<x<2.5`.
Is there a way to implement `x>d(1)` and `x>d(2)` in line 4 of the code to avoid `y < 0`? I would not want to solve this with a loop because I need to convert the formula to CDF later on.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Where is the loop that you want to avoid using?

Comment: @Robert There wasn't a loop in my script. Sorry for being unspecific on this. I edited the question.

Comment: On rereading the question, it seems to me that `max(y, 0)` returns the result you want. Maybe I am still not understanding what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot only for `x>max(d1,d2)`, you can use logical indexing:

`plot(x(x>max(d)),y(x>max(d)))`

If you to plot for all `x` but plot max(y,0), you just can write so:

`plot(x,max(y,0))`

Comment: Thanks for the nice tip on plotting. That's not really what I meant. I edited the question to make it more clear.